# Galaxy S4 video problem

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, youtube, video-recording

I've bought S4 yesterday.

Everything works great except recorded video or Youtube video starts to flicker/artifacts, green lines appears and eventually the video stops.

I've tried installing Nexus camera but that didn't work either.

Also when i play videos that are from my PC it works normally, no flicker or artifacts appears.

Tested for dead pixels but there is none:

Increased brightness to the max
Installed a free app called [Dead Pixel Test by UJACHA from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.ujacha.deadpixel)
Cycled through the colors and inspected the screen.

Here's the screenshots when playing youtube:

[image]
[image]

Dummy recording is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdq3ef2i5xgbc4l/S4_video_problem.mp4)

Should i return the cell and demand a new one?

Comment: So, you recorded the video on the PC using the S4's camera?

Comment: @geffchang I've recorded a dummy video using S4 camera, it's not watchable. The screenshots are also from S4 see the artifacts on bottom right corner. I'm returning it today.

Comment: What if you record something else, like not something from a PC / laptop. Is it OK?

Comment: Mind to hop over to chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android

Comment: @geffchang No matter what i record the problem is the same, as you can see i've tested to be sure. It's obviously from the bad batch of S4 series.

Comment: @ce4 Thanks but i've tested everything i needed to confirm that it's a defective device.

Comment: That's OK. Helping with determining a defective sample is usually faster via chat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm returning it today because the video is non-watchable, contains flicker and artifacts obviously it's from a bad batch (defective units out of the box, april 2013). At least I've tested it and saw artifacts when casting YouTube video to Google Chromecast.